# Check a bool on a lists all indexes

Tags: c#, list

Hello I want to do check a bool on lists all indexes. if all indexes bool is false: return false. Like this.
this code checks for each index, not like this.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Manager.Waves.Count; j++)
{
     if (Manager.Waves[j].IsEnd)
     {

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.All`:

```
bool noneEnded = Manager.Waves.All(w => !w.IsEnd);
```

or the opposite way:

```
bool noneEnded = ! Manager.Waves.Any(w => w.IsEnd);
```

Comment: Better to use `Any`, `All` would return true for an empty list.

Comment: @Habib What makes you think that's not the desired behavior?

Comment: @Servy,It was in the question. `if all indexes bool is false: return false`. Just mentioned it *in case*. May be it is not the desired behaviour, but my comment is there to clarify.